# regex ignore input that begins with + or 00 and matches only the rest of any digit total of 12

Tags: regex

I'm trying to make a regex that ignores '+' or '00' at beginning of the input, and matches only total of 12 digits of any (0-9).

For example, we have input which should match and not:

```
+886123456789 (matches)
00886123456789 (matches)
a0886123456789 (not matches)
!0886123456789 (not matches)
.886123456789 (not matches)
```

Here is my regex, and I have to ignore '+' or '00':

```
^[\\+]{0,1}[0-9]{12}$
```

Comment: Do you mean: [`^(?:\+|00)?(\d{12})$`](https://regex101.com/r/QtwNst/1) where your 1st capture group holds those 12 digits? or is it something other you are after?

Comment: Yes, it works now for 00. However it seems to fail for + sign result ? Please see screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/g2MeH6N.png

Comment: No @Kapparino. It does work. You just have to remove the trialing space character in your screenshot =)

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I've added an answer to help close the thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments above, you can use:

```
^(?:\+|00)?(\d{12})$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/QtwNst/1)

- `^` - Start line anchor.
- `(?:` - Open non-capture group.

  - `\+|00` - A literal "+" **or** a double zero.
  - `)?` - Close non-capture group and make it optional (to match 12 digits on its own to. Remove the "?" if you don't want this to happen).
- `(\d{12})` - Match exactly 12 digits in a capture group.
- `$` - End line anchor.